# matplotlib show single graph out of object of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have 18 data sets, and I've done showing all of 18 graphs using `plt.subplots` as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f,ax_array=plt.subplots(6,3)
for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(0,3):
        ax_array[i][j].plot(modified_data[3*i+j])
plt.show()
#modified data is my data set
```

What I want to do is show a single graph.  For example, how can I show a graph corresponding to `ax_array[3][2]`?

Answer (score 2):

That turns out to be not so easy, the easiest solution would be to create a new figure and issue the plot command again with the required data. Sharing axes objects across multiple figures is quite difficult.

However, solution below allows you to zoom in on a particular subplot using shift+left click.

```
def add_subplot_zoom(figure):

    zoomed_axes = [None]
    def on_click(event):
        ax = event.inaxes

        if ax is None:
            # occurs when a region not in an axis is clicked...
            return

        # we want to allow other navigation modes as well. Only act in case
        # shift was pressed and the correct mouse button was used
        if event.key != 'shift' or event.button != 1:
            return

        if zoomed_axes[0] is None:
            # not zoomed so far. Perform zoom

            # store the original position of the axes
            zoomed_axes[0] = (ax, ax.get_position())
            ax.set_position([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.85])

            # hide all the other axes...
            for axis in event.canvas.figure.axes:
                if axis is not ax:
                    axis.set_visible(False)

        else:
            # restore the original state

            zoomed_axes[0][0].set_position(zoomed_axes[0][1])
            zoomed_axes[0] = None

            # make other axes visible again
            for axis in event.canvas.figure.axes:
                axis.set_visible(True)

        # redraw to make changes visible.
        event.canvas.draw()

    figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
```

[Source](https://www.semipol.de/2015/09/04/matplotlib-interactively-zooming-to-a-subplot.html). Calling the function in your example as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f,ax_array=plt.subplots(6,3)
for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(0,3):
        ax_array[i][j].plot(modified_data[3*i+j])

add_subplot_zoom(f)

plt.show()
```